# Error while Iterating values from Bean

Tags: java, arrays

I'm taking the `resultset` values into the bean `PorgInfo`. It has values like

program,Group,Org. Trying to get particular Org belong to the specific group

and that group belong to specific Program

through loop like below

```
 Map m = jdbcCall.execute(in );
 for(PorgInfo gInfo: m.get("PorgInfo")){ //**Can only iterate over an array or an instance  of java.lang.Iterable**
//Planned to goahead like below but can't proceed bcz of above issue
  for(Program pgm: temp1){
  for(Group gpm:temp2){
  ..................
 }
```

so from `PorgInfo` i need to take `Program1` which has Group1 which has Org 1 ,Program2 which has Group2 which has Org 2 ...

Please let me know if i'm missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the value of `m.get("PorgInfo")` return an Iterable like a list or set?

Comment: is it m.get("porgInfo") returns collection ?